# AppleScript: Can we obtain the argument vector of a called handler as a list?

Tags: applescript

AppleScript error messages appear to imply that the set of arguments supplied to multi-parameter handlers is internally represented as a list.

Short of refactoring all handlers to take list or record arguments, can we:

1. Learn, at run-time, the number of arguments expected by a given handler object ?
2. Obtain, at run-time, some kind of argv list of arguments supplied to a multi-parameter handler (or perhaps a record representation of the nameSpace defined within a handler)  ?

Comment: 1.) No - 2.) No

Comment: (1.) Is not of course, technically impossible – we can certainly scrape an error message string at run-time – but something cleaner would be good.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found no route to (2.) (obtaining the argument list at runtime) but for what it's worth, here is a function which (at the risk of producing side effects if the arity of the handler is 0), does allow us to learn the arity of a handler at run-time.

```
-- RUN-TIME TEST:
-- HOW MANY ARGUMENTS DOES A HANDLER EXPECT ? --------------------------------

-- arityAndMaybeValue :: Handler -> {arity: Int, nothing: Bool, just: Any}
on arityAndMaybeValue(h)
    try
        set v to mReturn(h)'s |λ|()
        {arity:0, nothing:false, just:v}
    on error errMsg
        {arity:length of splitOn(",", errMsg), nothing:true}
    end try
end arityAndMaybeValue

-- TEST ----------------------------------------------------------------------
on run
    -- Arities for zipWith and helloWorld handlers

    {arityAndMaybeValue(zipWith), arityAndMaybeValue(helloWorld)}

    -- If the arity was 0, then a return value is is given 
    -- in the 'just' key of the record returned.
    -- otherwise, the 'nothing' key contains the value `true`

    --> {{arity:3, nothing:true}, {arity:0, nothing:false, just:"hello world!"}}
end run

-- SAMPLE HANDLERS TO TEST FOR ARITY AT RUN-TIME -----------------------------

-- helloWorld :: () -> String
on helloWorld()
    "hello world!"
end helloWorld

-- zipWith :: (a -> b -> c) -> [a] -> [b] -> [c]
on zipWith(f, xs, ys)
    set lng to min(length of xs, length of ys)
    set lst to {}
    tell mReturn(f)
        repeat with i from 1 to lng
            set end of lst to |λ|(item i of xs, item i of ys)
        end repeat
        return lst
    end tell
end zipWith


-- GENERIC FUNCTIONS ---------------------------------------------------------

-- splitOn :: Text -> Text -> [Text]
on splitOn(strDelim, strMain)
    set {dlm, my text item delimiters} to {my text item delimiters, strDelim}
    set xs to text items of strMain
    set my text item delimiters to dlm
    return xs
end splitOn

-- Lift 2nd class handler function into 1st class script wrapper 
-- mReturn :: Handler -> Script
on mReturn(f)
    if class of f is script then
        f
    else
        script
            property |λ| : f
        end script
    end if
end mReturn
```